# Template class and related classes

Tags: function, templates

I'm writing a code for a basic adt text editor with a doubly linked list ( for HW ) and Ive run across the error C2244:'Editor::run_command ' :unable to match function to existing declaration. I orignalyy declared the function in my Editor class but i have to use Template  in order to use some of the variables from a template class if someon could help me out i'd appreicate it a ton

```
 // assignment 2-2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class Node_entry>
struct Node {
// data members
Node_entry entry;
Node<Node_entry> *next;
Node<Node_entry> *back;
// constructors
Node( );
~Node();
Node(Node_entry, Node<Node_entry> *link_back = NULL,
Node<Node_entry> *link_next = NULL);
};

template <class List_entry>
class List {
public:
// methods of the List ADT
List( );
    int size( ) const;
    bool full( ) const;
    bool empty( ) const;    
    void clear( );
    int count;
    error_code traverse(void (*visit)(List_entry &));
    error_code retrieve(int position, List_entry &x) const;
    error_code remove(int position, List_entry &x);
    error_code insert(int position, const List_entry &x);
protected:
// data members for a contiguous list implementation

    List_entry entry[15];
    mutable int current_position;
    mutable Node<List_entry> *current;

     void set_position(int position) const
     {
         if (current position <= position)
            for ( ; current_position != position; current_position++)
                current = current->next;
        else
            for ( ; current_position != position; current_position−−)
                current = current->back;
     }
};


template <class List_entry>
int List<List_entry>::size( ) const
{
return count;
};


template <class List_entry>
error_code List<List_entry>::insert(int position, const List_entry &x)
    {
Node<List_entry> *new_node, *following, *preceding;
if (position < 0 || position > count) return range_error;

if (position == 0) {
    if (count == 0) following = NULL;
    else {
    set_position(0);
    following = current;
        }
    preceding = NULL;
    }
else {
    set_position(position − 1);
    preceding = current;
    following = preceding->next;
    }
new_node = new Node<List_entry>(x, preceding, following);
if (new_node == NULL) 
    return overflow;
if (preceding != NULL) 
    preceding->next = new_node;
if(following != NULL) following->back = new_node;
current=new_node;
current_position=position;
count++;
return success;
};

class Editor: public List<string> {
public:
    Editor(ifstream *file_in, ofstream *file_out);
    bool get_command( );
    void run_command( );

private:
    ifstream *infile;
    ofstream *outfile;
    char user_command;
// auxiliary functions
    error_code next_line( );
    error_code previous_line( );
    error_code goto_line( );
    error_code insert_line( );
    error_code substitute_line( );
    error_code change_line( );
    void write_file( );
    void read_file( );
    void find_string( );
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
if (argc != 3) {
    cout << "Usage:\n\t edit inputfile outputfile" << endl;
    exit (1);
    }
ifstream file_in(argv[1]); // Declare and open the input stream.
if (file_in == 0) {
    cout << "Cant open input file " << argv[1] << endl;
    exit (1);
    }
ofstream file_out(argv[2]); // Declare and open the output stream.
if (file_out == 0) {
    cout << "Cant open output file " << argv[2] << endl;
    exit (1);
    }
Editor buffer( &file_in, &file_out);
while (buffer.get_command())
    buffer.run_command();
}

Editor::Editor(ifstream *file_in, ofstream *file_out)
{
infile = file_in;
outfile = file_out;
};

bool Editor::get_command( )
{
    if (current != NULL)
    cout << current_position << " : "<< current->entry.c_str( ) << "\n??" << flush;
else
    cout << "File is empty.\n??" << flush;
cin >> user_command; // ignores white space and gets command
user_command = tolower(user_command);
while(cin.get( ) != '\n')
; // ignore user’s enter key
if(user_command == 'q')
    return false;
else
    return true;
};

template <class List_entry>
void Editor::run_command( )
{
string temp_string;
cout << "Press h or ? for help or enter a valid command: ";

if(user_command=='b'){
    if (empty( ))
        cout << " Warning: empty buffer " << endl;
    else
        while (previous_line( ) == success);
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='c'){
    if (empty( ))
        cout << " Warning: Empty file" << endl;
    else if (change_line( ) != success)
        cout << " Error: Substitution failed " << endl;
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='d'){
        if (remove(current_position, temp_string) != success)
            cout << " Error: Deletion failed " << endl;
        goto point;;}
if(user_command=='e'){
    if(empty())
        cout<<"Warning: Buffer is empty"<<endl
    else
        while (next_line( ) == success)
            ;
    goto point;}
if(user_command=='f'){
    if (empty( )) cout << " Warning: Empty file" << endl;
    else 
        find_string( );
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='g'){
    if (goto_line( ) != success)
        cout << " Warning: No such line" << endl;
    goto point;}
if(user_command=='?'||user_command=="h"){
    cout << "Valid commands are: b(egin) c(hange) d(el) e(nd)"
    << endl
    << "f(ind) g(o) h(elp) i(nsert) l(ength) n(ext) p(rior) " << endl
    << "q(uit) r(ead) s(ubstitute) v(iew) w(rite) " << endl;}
if(user_command=='i'){
    if (insert_line( ) != success)
        cout << " Error: Insertion failed " << endl;
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='l'){
    cout << "There are " << size( ) << " lines in the file." << endl;
    if (!empty( ))
        cout << "Current line length is "<< strlen((current->entry).c_str( )) << endl;
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='n'){
    if (next_line( ) != success)
        cout << " Warning: at end of buffer" << endl;
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='p'){
    if (previous_line( ) != success)
    cout << " Warning: at start of buffer" << endl;
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='r'){

    read_file( );
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='s'){
    if (substitute_line( ) != success)
        cout << " Error: Substitution failed " << endl;
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='v'){

    traverse(write);
    goto point;;}
if(user_command=='w'){

    if (empty( ))
        cout << " Warning: Empty file" << endl;
    else
        write_file( );
    goto point;}
point:

};
void Editor::read_file( )
{
bool proceed = true;
if (!empty( )) {
    cout << "Buffer is not empty; the read will destroy it." << endl;
    cout << " OK to proceed? " << endl;
    cout<<"(Y)es or (N)0"<<endl;
    char choice;
    cin>>choice;
    if (choice=='y') clear( );
}
int line_number = 0, terminal_char;
while (proceed) {
    ifstream read_in;
    read_in.open("hw.txt");
    string in_string;
    read_in>>in_string;
    if (terminal_char == EOF) {
        proceed = false;
        if (strlen(in_string.c_str( )) > 0) insert(line_number, in_string);
            }
    else insert(line_number++, in_string);
    }
};
error_code Editor::insert_line( ){
int line_number;
cout << " Insert what line number? " << flush;
cin >> line_number;
while (cin.get( ) != 'n');
cout << " What is the new line to insert? " << flush;
string userString;
cin>>userString;
string to_insert = userString;
return insert(line_number, to_insert);
};
```

Comment: When you define `run_command` as a template, what is your goal exactly? Who is going to supply an actual argument for `List_entry`?

Comment: TO be honest with you I built this code using the powerpoint of some programming professor i found online, what I do understand is that if i dont add the template the run_command cant use the variable from the other classes

Comment: Which variables from which other classes?

Comment: Variables like success become undefined

Comment: `success` is never defined in your code. Templates or no templates, it is undefined. You cannot stick `template` in front of your function and magically make it able to access something that does not exist. I suggest you don't attempt to learn C++ out of a some powerpoint you find online, the experience is guaranteed to be frustrating. Get a book.